# How to define Pagination Policy in Azure Data Factory - Data Flows?

Tags: azure, rest, pagination, azure-data-factory

I have to fetch data from **CATS Applicant Tracking System**. As the response is usually huge, so the API sends the response in Pages.

For Example (If I make a request to: https://api.catsone.com/v3/candidates/search?page=1&per_page=100), I get this:

[image]

Here in this image:

**Count:** No of entities (Candidates) returned in this response.

**Total:** Total no of entities (Candidates).

**Self:** Relative link to Current Page

**Next:** Relative link to Next Page

**Last:** Relative link to Last Page

The issue I am facing is that this API returns **/candidates/** appended at the start of the Next link. My linked Service already has **/candidates/** appended in the base Url because if I will not mention **/candidates/** in the base URL, I will not get any response.

So if I append the base Url defined in Linked Service with the next URL that is returned it becomes an invalid Url (**/candidates/** appearing 2 times in the resulting URL): https://api.catsone.com/v3/candidates/candidates/search?page=2&per_page=100

I tried to alter the returned next Url (By replacing **/candidates/** with an empty string) but it's not possible, might be ADF currently does not support it:

[image]

ADF Data Flows do not support range pagination, otherwise, I could have calculated the end page from the count and total and used that instead :).

As a result, I am doing pagination through ForEach Loop but in this case, Data Flow spawns a
separate cluster for each page each time. Which are time and cost-consuming.

Please guide me on how I can define pagination policy in such a scenario. I do not want to use ForEach Loop.

Comment: try by adding `https://api.catsone.com/v3` as relative URL and then try to pass **next page** link in pagination rule.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thanks for the response. I can try that. But I am pretty sure that it will not work because "https://api.catsone.com/v3" will not return the next page URL that we can use. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce with your API but it has authorization so I can't

The I took sample API URL `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1` and tried pagination with alternate approach

for this take a for-each activity in settings tick the sequential and add dynamic content to Items as **@range(1,7)** as you know that your Api contains 7 pages from last page link.

[image]

Add data flow activity in it and add your rest API as source, create parameter with name query and type string. Now, in relative URL add Dynamic value as `@dataset().query`

[image]

After that in dataflow in source parameter add remaining api with dynamic value for page

[image]

**Successfully Iterated through each page**

[image]

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thanks for the response. As I mentioned, I am already using ForEach loop. But I want to use Pagination Policy instead of ForEach.

Comment: Can you please provide authorization details to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry PratikLad, I cannot. Because it has all the admin access of my company. :)